# JQuery Scroll To Anchor Only On First Scroll

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a JQuery solution to automatically scroll to the first anchor point on a page on only the first scroll action.

The opening of the website is a full screen video with a down arrow letting the user know they can scroll down for more sections.  If the user uses the scroll wheel, I want it to instantly slide down to the first section and after that it can go back to normal scrolling.

Is there a possible solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a flag and only perform the action if it is false and set it to true on first scroll:

```js
window.wasScrolled = false;
$(window).bind('scroll',function(){
    if (!window.wasScrolled){ $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:document.getElementById('to').getBoundingClientRect().top},1000)}
    window.wasScrolled = true;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:4000px"></div>
<div id="to" style="background:black;height:10000px"></div>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tj14vs2c/)

Comment: This is working, other than it appears to not go all the way to the anchor point and stops about 30-60 pixels short.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Because the div had only 100px height and it can't cover the whole screen. Try it again, I've added some more height @Cole

Comment: I'm sorry.  I was referring to my actual page I am testing it on.  It stops short.  I also have a fixed header I have to offset by -60px as well.  It's close, just need to get it to line up correctly.  Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: What's strange is when using the down arrow it goes all the way to the anchor point but with a scroll it doesn't.

Comment: Strange. Did you set any margin to the element or are there any elements that might change height during scroll happens? Might be that you need to subtract it.

Comment: Nope.  The Section has no margins.  It works correctly in Firefox.  Chrome and IE appear to not go to the anchor exactly on scroll.

Comment: Hard to say from here why this is happening.

Comment: I found a solution by changing the scrollTop a bit.

`$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#featured').position().top}, 1000);`

Comment: I thought about that to, but does it fit in every browser now? @Cole

Comment: It appears to be working in all browsers with that change to the animate.  Thanks for your help Michael.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Here's the snippet if someone happens to have fixed navigation they need to offset for.

`$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#featured').offset().top - $('.nav-bar').outerHeight(true)}, 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a one() method for executing a bound function a single time.

```js
$('.scroll').one('scroll', function(e) {
  // jump to section
  // window.location.hash = 'section';
  alert('jumping to #section');
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scroll div {
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">
  <div>
    scroll me
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <a id="section" name="section">first section</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the y position of the first 'A' element with a 'Name' attribute (bookmark) then scroll to that position with an animation then Unbind the Scroll event so it does not trigger again.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
  var destination = $('a[name]').offset().top;
  //jQuery UI needed for animate function
  $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: destination}, 600, "easeOutExpo", function(){});
  unbindScroll();
});     

function unbindScroll(){
  $(window).unbind("scroll");
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/ct3vkkr0/